# Ordering of bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have looked through the answers in this forum but cannot seem to find an answer to this specific problem. I have the following data and want to create a bar chart where the bars are ordered from largest to smallest in terms of "Value", rather than having them in alphabetical order:

```
breadth_data <- read.table(textConnection("Stakeholder  Value
'Grantseekers'  0.90
'Donors'    0.89
'Community' 0.55
'Hurricane Relief Fund' 0.24
'Media' 0.19
'Employment Seekers'    0.12
'Affiliates'    0.10
'Youth' 0.09
'Women' 0.02
'Former Board Members'  0.01"), header=TRUE)
```

Then the basic bar chart:

```
c <- ggplot(breadth_data, aes(x=Stakeholder, y=Value))
c + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous('') + scale_x_discrete('')
```

I have tried many of the different reorderings and transformations I've seen on StackOverflow but I cannot seem to find one that works. I am sure this is fairly simple, but I would appreciate any help!

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You want function `reorder()`:

```
breadth_data <- transform(breadth_data, 
                          Stakeholder = reorder(Stakeholder, Value))
```

Which gives:

[image: reordered barplot]

If you want them the other way round, an easy way is just to use `order()` on `Value` inside the `reorder()` call:

```
breadth_data <- transform(breadth_data,
                          Stakeholder = reorder(Stakeholder, 
                                                order(Value, decreasing = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Or use `-Value` inside the call to `reorder` to reverse the direction.

Comment: @Richie - of course (slaps face!) - clearly not thinking straight this arvo!

Comment: I also use 1/Value to re-order in the opposite direction.  It worked! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using the [`fct_reorder`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html) function from [`forcats`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org) package. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
ggplot(breadth_data, aes(x=fct_reorder(Stakeholder, Value), y=Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_continuous('') + 
  scale_x_discrete('')
```

[image]

Use `fct_rev` for reversing order:

```r
# Reverse order
ggplot(breadth_data, aes(x=fct_rev(fct_reorder(Stakeholder, Value)), y=Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_continuous('') + 
  scale_x_discrete('')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>