# ggplot2: reorder bars in barplot from highest to lowest

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got this figure

[image]

Following the answer of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967593/ordering-of-bars-in-ggplot)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

mydf <- transform(mydf, variables = reorder(variables, VIP, decreasing = T))

p1 <- 
  ggplot(mydf, aes(x = variables, y = VIP, group =1))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, size = 2, linetype = 3) +
  theme(axis.title.x =element_blank())
p2 <-
  ggplot(mydf, aes(x = variables, y = coefficient, group =1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 2, linetype = 3) 

grid.draw(egg::ggarrange(p1,p2 , ncol=1))
```

My goal was to order the bars from highest to lowest.

Although, I sorted the `variables and VIP` from highest to lowest, the bars were ordered from lowest to highest.

Any idea what went wrong and made the bars sorted from lowest to highest?

**Data**

```
mydf <- read.table(text = c("
variables   VIP coefficient
diesel  0.705321    0.19968224
twodoors    1.2947119   0.3387236
sportsstyle 0.8406462   -0.25861398
wheelbase   1.3775179   -0.42541873
length  0.8660376   0.09322408
width   0.8202489   0.27762277
height  1.0140934   -0.12334574
curbweight  0.996365    -0.29504266
enginesize  0.8601269   -0.25321317
horsepower  0.7093094   0.16587358
horse_per_weight    1.2389938   0.43380122"), header = T)
```

Comment: There is no argument `decreasing ` in the reorder function. If you replace your reorder call with `reorder(variables, -VIP)` ist should work.

Comment: @Alex
Thanks for your time and help. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to a wrong use of `reorder`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

mydf <- transform(mydf, variables = reorder(variables, -VIP))

p1 <- 
  ggplot(mydf, aes(x = variables, y = VIP))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, size = 2, linetype = 3) +
  theme(axis.title.x =element_blank())
p2 <-
  ggplot(mydf, aes(x = variables, y = coefficient, group = 1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 2, linetype = 3) 

grid.draw(egg::ggarrange(p1,p2 , ncol=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. As I want line + point in the bottom plot, I had to use group = 1. Without using group =1, the bottom plot will be points only without line.

Comment: I did not notice this. Then you need group in your second plot.